# Why does the python pathlib Path('').exists() return True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib, file-exists

I was expecting `Path('')` to be a path that does not exist because it does not correspond to a file or directory name. Why is this considered to exist?

```
from pathlib import Path

print(Path('').exists())
```

I assume there is an advantage gained by defining the `Path('')` to be the same as `Path('.')`. In what case is there an advantage?

Comment: Because it resolves to the current directory, which exists

Comment: See `Path('') == Path() == Path('.')`

Comment: Try `print(Path('').resolve())`. On my machine it gives `C:\Users\PeterWood\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32`

Answer (score 19):

As other said, it resolves to the current path and therefore exists, but here's why,

[pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) is acutally a subclass of [pathlib.PurePath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath) which assumes the current directory when the `pathsegments` (argument) is empty (equivalent to `''`).

You can prove that empirically like this,

```
from pathlib import PurePath
print(PurePath())
>>>> .
```

> I assume there is an advantage gained by defining the Path('') to be the same as Path('.').

Correct. Even though I'm not the creator of that lib, I assume this is for syntax and logical reasons. Indeed, people often want to refer to the current directory to compute something dynamically. Therefore, for the same reason `.` points to the current directory, the lib creator probably wanted to let you write something like this,

```
>>>> p = Path() # or possibly Path('.')
>>> [x for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir()]
```

that would list sub directories.

Basically, see this as a ***default***. It was logic that the default path returned by `Path()` was the current directory. Thus, logically, an empty string value should have the same behavior.

Comment: @mattm Consider accepting this answer. I think it's valid one...

Answer (score 5):

If you try `stat` you get:

```
$ touch ""
touch: cannot touch '': No such file or directory
```

but if you peek inside, the story is different:

```
$ strace -e file touch ""
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=122530, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

So you can stat `""` because it's the CWD, but you can't open it as a file because no such file exists. Indeed:

```
$ strace -e file ipython3 
In [1]: import pathlib

In [2]: p = pathlib.Path()

In [3]: p.exists()
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, ".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}, 0) = 0
Out[3]: True
```

So this is not exactly any kind of assumption from Python's `pathlib` module, but all the way down the the C lib and kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly off topic: I want to have a Path whose boolean value is False. Seems to be not possible. I'm doing this inside argparse with type=Path. I suspect that OP wanted something similar.

I ended up using one of two options, neither as "elegant" as it would be if I could simply test "if the_possibly_false_Path:..."

1. Set the default (which I wish tested False) to something like '%%'
   which causes argparse to create a Path with the name "%%" which I
   can then test for
2. Leave the result as a default type, set the default to something
   that tests False and then call the Path constructor if the value
   isn't false.

Comment: Same. But maybe raising an exception is the way to go instead. Personally I'm not fond of raising an exception to perform what is basically an if-else, but ...